# How to get javac flags from a compiled class

Tags: java, javac

Is it possible to get javac flags that was set when a class was compiled? I mean I have a 3rd party library and I can't debug its class in Eclipse because *line: not available*.

I would like to see what flags was used when the library was compiled.
[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2885526/eclipse-debug-line-not-available) is a similar problem I have. Its author writes:

> Looking at javac compile flags, I see the -g:none flag.

So is it possible to see those flags?

Comment: Every distinct value for `javac -g:*` has a different result, like adding/removing source line numbers, so a simple [javap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javap.html#options) disassembly with appropiate options would give info.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it with `javap` util. Run it with `-v` flag. If src was compiled with `-g:source` option javap will print file path in the first line of the output

```
Classfile /D:/workspace/x/target/classes/test/Test2.class
...
```

if `-g:vars` was used then you will see var names in LocalVariableTable

```
  LocalVariableTable:
    Start  Length  Slot  Name   Signature
           0      31     0  args   [Ljava/lang/String;
  ...
```

if `-g:lines` was used then javap will print LineNumberTable

```
LineNumberTable:
 line 12: 0
 ...
```

You can also read these things programmatically with eg BCEL:

```
    JavaClass jc = Repository.lookupClass(Test2.class);
    String sf = jc.getSourceFileName();
    Method m = jc.getMethods()[0];
    LineNumberTable ln = m.getLineNumberTable();
    LocalVariableTable lvt = m.getLocalVariableTable();
```

Comment: This works. Although this way I can't still get flags used to compile class. If nobody comes up with a better answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: No you wont see flags directly, class file format is strict http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se5.0/html/ClassFile.doc.html it does not contain compilation flags

Comment: javap -l option will give you the line number table details alone